# Passing a C# object into a lua function with moonsharp.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua, mono, moonsharp

I'm having issues using Moonsharp in Unity3d. I'm trying to pass 'AppletMessage' objects:

```
[MoonSharpUserData]
public class AppletMessage {
    public string Name;
    public string[] Args;

    public AppletMessage(string _name, string[] _args) {
        Name = _name;
        Args = _args;
    }
}
```

into a function in lua and I'm not sure how to do that.
What I'm currently doing is this:

```
//In a start function
UserData.RegisterType<AppletMessage>();

//Later on, after popping the latest message from a stack as 'LatestMessage'
result = applet.Call( applet.Globals["OnCatchMessage"],new AppletMessage[] {LatestMessage});
```

this is giving me this error coming from the applet class when it tries to call the function and pass the AppletMessage in:

```
cannot access field  of userdata<AppletMessage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `Moonsharp.Interpreter.UserData.RegisterAssembly();` when your game starts? You need this to detect and make the `[MoonSharpUserData]` tags work properly.

Comment: if you are not sure this is the answer you should make it as a comment (you need 10 points for that)

Comment: you have to answer one question correctly. We all earned the privileges

Comment: Ok, I'll try! But I think my answer is correct, at least from my experience with Moonsharp that seems to be the most probable cause of the error.